Own character animation not working Mixamo
I m new to character animation, I m exploring blender rigging to do the animation on my character.  
While uploading it to mixamo this is the result. I m not able to proceed. Can someone help?


I'm afraid you haven't given us enough details to even guess what's causing the problem. In any case we can't help with external software such as Mixamo. If you can share your Blend file we might be able to see a problem with it.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by some accompanying screenshots with the [edit] button under the question. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mixamo+upload+my+skeleton&oq=mixamo+upload+my+skeleton&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigAdIBCTE2NDE0ajBqN6gCFLACAQ&client=tablet-android-lenovo-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

It may be that your character is not aligned correctly along the X/Y axis. Try realigning it and see if that helps.
